# Unable to access generated java files

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, grpc

My project uses gRPC and it generates a file in generated folder.

[image]

This is my build.gradle of the module.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.4.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.4.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.4.0'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"


apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
def grpcVersion = '1.4.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0'
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {
                // To generate deprecated interfaces and static bindService method,
                // turn the enable_deprecated option to true below:
                option 'enable_deprecated=false'
            }
        }
    }
}


// Inform IntelliJ projects about the generated code.
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        // Not using generatedSourceDirs because of
        // https://discuss.gradle.org/t/support-for-intellij-2016/15294/8
        sourceDirs += file("${projectDir}/build/generated/source/proto/main/java");
        sourceDirs += file("${projectDir}/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc");
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add this folder to your source sets.
The following should work:

```
sourceSets {
   generated{
        java.srcDir "${projectDir}/build/generated/source/proto/main/java"
   }
}
```

[Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:working_with_java_source_sets) is a comprehensive documentation for customizing the source sets.

Comment: Your answer inspired me. Thanks so much.

Comment: @LoveRight, no problem, you're welcome to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out. My iml file includes the folder but also excludes it. I think exclusion takes precedence, so I have to remvoe the `<excludeFolder>` element.

[image]